# Verificar quais processos estão conectados à internet

Tags: c#, .net, redes

É possível verificar quais são os processos estão conectados à internet e qual é o seu destino?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Não parece algo muito simples. Também nunca tentei fazer isto mas achei [algumas respostas no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273296/221800).

Parece que a forma mais simples é chamar um processo externo e executar o utilitário do Windows para informar isto. Seria algo como:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process { //se usar o using não precisa do namespace
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        StartInfo.FileName = "netstat.exe";
        StartInfo.Arguments = "-abnot";
        StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    }
}
process.Start();
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // faz alguma coisa com o conteúdo de cada linha recebida do processo
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/ProcessInternetUsing.cs).

Também existe a alternativa de usar P/Invoke e criar um acesso à API com [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas eu não sei como fazer.

Achei [uma resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577660/221800) que mostra como fazer pelo menos o acesso básico (não sei se resolve para você). É, não é simples.

Answer (score 0):

Da para fazer utilizando [WMI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/about-wmi).
Fazendo uma consulta na tabela [MSFT_NetTCPConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/nettcpipprov/msft-nettcpconnection).

Veja um exemplo:

```
public enum TcpState
{
    Closed = 1,
    Listen = 2,
    SynSent = 3,
    SynReceived = 4,
    Established = 5,
    FinWait1 = 6,
    FinWait2 = 7,
    CloseWait = 8,
    Closing = 9,
    LastAck = 10,
    TimeWait = 11,
    DeleteTCB = 12
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\StandardCimv2");
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetTCPConnection");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();


    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(m["OwningProcess"].ToString(), out int r))
        {
            var processInfo = Process.GetProcessById(r);
            WriteLine("LocalPort: {0} - State: {1} - Process {2}", m["LocalPort"], Enum.GetName(typeof(TcpState), m["state"]), processInfo.ProcessName);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```